# With $u\in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ $T$-periodic, show that $u(nx)$ as a distribution converges to a constant

Tags: distribution-theory, periodic-functions

> Let $u\in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ be $T$-periodic. Given $u_n(x)=u(nx)$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, show that $u_n$ converges to a constant $c$ in the sense of the convergence in the distribution space $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$ and compute such constant.

So I need to show that exists a constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for any test function $\varphi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ $$\langle u_n,\varphi\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}}u(nx)\varphi(x)\text{d}x \to \int_{\mathbb{R}}c\varphi(x)\text{d}x = \langle c,\varphi\rangle, \quad \text{for }n\to\infty.$$

Any hints on how to tackle this question?

Comment: Integrate by parts to make $\int_0^x u(ny)dy=\frac1n U(nx)$ appear. Also the condition $u\in L^1_{loc}$ is not needed, that it is a distribution suffices.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $ U(nT) = n U(T) $ as $u$ is $T$-periodic.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @reuns. How can a distribution be periodic in the general case? Distributions are linear continuous operators from test functions to the complex plane. Can't we talk of periodicity only when a distribution is induced by a function?

Comment: $\langle f,\phi\rangle=\langle f,\phi(.+T)\rangle$  means that $f$ is periodic

Comment: Please, @reuns can you explain more your hint, $(u_n)'(\phi)=-(u_n(\phi'))=-\int u_n(x)\phi'(x)=-\int u_(nx)\phi'(x)$, is enought integrate over any compact K like $[0,x]$, i will appreciate your help, i like the excercise!! but i am still confuse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $u$ is only assumed to be a $T$-periodic distribution it is a bit trickier than just an integration by parts and $\int_0^x u(y)dy=cx+O(1)$ where $c=\frac1T\int_0^T u(y)dy$.

Say $T=1$. From a convolution with $(1-|x|)1_{|x|< 1}$ construct $\psi \in C^\infty_c$ such that $\sum_k \psi(.+k)=1$.

Then $$\langle u(n.),\phi \rangle=
\langle u,\frac1n\phi(\frac{.}n) \rangle=\langle u,\sum_k \psi(.+k)\frac1n\phi(\frac{.}n)  \rangle=
\langle u,\psi \sum_k \frac1n\phi(\frac{.+k}n) \rangle
$$

$ \sum_k \frac1n\phi(\frac{.+k}n)$ is smooth and all its derivatives $\to 0$ uniformly. Whence $\psi \sum_k \frac1n\phi(\frac{.+k}n)\to a \psi$ in the $C_c^\infty$ topology, where $a=\langle 1,\phi\rangle$, and hence $$\langle u,\psi \sum_k \frac1n\phi(\frac{.+k}n) \rangle\to \langle u,a\psi \rangle = c\langle 1,\phi \rangle, \qquad c= \langle u,\psi \rangle$$